# Calling a parametrized method form c:foreach to create the selectItem of the selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

I am trying to build the selectOneMenu dynamically based on the return List from `convertJsonToList` method. I have tried with `f:selectItems, c:forEach, ui:repeat` but without seccuss ...For more information please take a look at the code below.

How can I call the parametrized convertJsonToList on the `selectOneMenu` dropdown?

```
      <p:selectOneMenu  id="selectOneMenu"  scrollHeight="100" 
         value="#{viewEventStatusController.operationId}"  autoWidth="false" style="#{componentUnit.style}" styleClass="selectOperationOneMenu" rendered="#{componentUnit.type == 'selectOneMenu'}">

          <!-- I have to set an index, therefore I tried to use forEach -->  
          <f:selectItems value="#{viewEventStatusController.convertJsonToList(chat.operations)}" var="opration" itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{operation}" />                                               

          <!-- Here the  convertJsonToList is not being called I think because it is parametrized!-->
          <c:forEach items="#{viewEventStatusController.convertJsonToList(chat.operations)}" var="operation" varStatus="count">
              <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{operation}"   itemValue="#{count.index}" />
          </c:forEach>

           <!-- the convertJsonToList method is not being called!  -->
          <ui:repeat value="#{viewEventStatusController.convertJsonToList(chat.operations)}">
          </ui:repeat>

      </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Does it work with a plain jsf `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: Can you show the bean method (`convertJsonToList`)?

Comment: It works for me now if I do the following: ` <f:selectItems value="#{viewEventStatusController.convertJsonToList(chat.operations)}" var="operation" itemValue="#{viewEventStatusController.getOperationIndex(operation)}" itemLabel="#{operation}" />` I wrote a method `getOperationIndex` to get the index in the bean

Comment: Try just changing your bean method to `getConvertJsonToList`, without further changes.